# Angular JS detach event handler

Tags: javascript, angularjs, events

I'm looking for a way to release an event when linked on this way:

```
angular.element($document[0].body).on('click', function (e) {
           // code
});
```

Any clue?

Comment: `angular.element($document[0].body).off('click');`

Comment: wow that was crazy fast! Let me try that

Comment: Be aware that will disable all click handlers for that selector, that were registered with 'on'. Of course, if that is the only one then no problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
// handler
var handler = function (e) { }    

angular.element($document[0].body).on('click', handler);


// afterwards
angular.element($document[0].body).off('click', handler);
```

Also check if you're using `jQuery` or `jqLite` (https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element, Angular's implementation). You might try to do unsupported things if you use the latter.

Comment: The OPs code is using an anon function so Im not sure this will work if he can't refactor code to avoid that.

Comment: +1 I guess best practice is to separate out anon handler to named function and set the reference. So that you are _turning off_ only that click handler.

Comment: +1, I like surgical solutions that don't suprise me in the future.